# in regex how could one match quotes and dots for c# programming

Tags: c#, regex

i am in need of regex to the following problem

i have a line like this "ApplicationPackage + ".SAVE", parameters," in C# language
how could i get only match and get SAVE as a result using regex pattern matching

thanks in advance

Comment: You can include a quote by escaping it with the backslash character \, e.g. "\"".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to match SAVE only if it is between ". and "

```
var match = Regex.Match(yourStringHere, @"(?<=""\.)SAVE(?="")");
if(match.Success)
    //do what you want with match.Value
```

If you want any word between ". and " , then use the appropriate wildcard instead of SAVE

e.g with \w

```
var match = Regex.Match(yourStringHere, @"(?<=""\.)\w+(?="")");
```

And be careful if you choose to use . don't forget to use a lazy quantifier

```
var match = Regex.Match(yourStringHere, @"(?<=""\.).+?(?="")");
```

Answer (score 0):

use slash () to include special characters 
e.g. . or \"